# ImportError: No module named 'tweepy.streaming'; 'tweepy' is not a package

Tags: python, tweepy

I wrote this tweepy sourcecode in PyCharm ed 4.

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, print_function
from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
from tweepy import Stream

consumer_key="***"
consumer_secret="***"
access_token="***"
access_token_secret="***"

class StdOutListener(StreamListener):
    def on_data(self, data):
         print(data)
         return True

    def on_error(self, status):
         print(status)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    l = StdOutListener()
    auth = OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
    auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)

    stream = Stream(auth, l)
    stream.filter(track=['basketball'])
```

However, I got this message from program.

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2195, in _find_and_load_unlocked
 AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '__path__'

 During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

 file:***,in lin3, in module
 from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener
 file:***, in line 3, in module
 from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener

 ImportError: No module named 'tweepy.streaming'; 'tweepy' is not a package
```

I don't know what's wrong with my execution.
Please help me.

Comment: what's the bet that you saved your own python script as tweepy.py?

Comment: I don't know what's your saying.

Comment: what is the name of the file that holds your python code above?

Answer (score 3):

After reviewing several answers and trying them out myself...

Make sure that:

- Your script is not named tweepy.py
- Tweepy is installed through pip
- Try to import OAuthHandler by doing

  `from tweepy import OAuthHandler`
- **You delete your .pyc files after trying another solution** (this is where I was failing)

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

your file name should not be tweepy.py. if it is, then it will import itself.

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks.