# OAuthHandler not loading from Tweepy properly

Tags: python, tweepy

I use Python 3.4.2 and aquired Tweepy here: https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy

Tweepy is showing as properly installed but not loading OAuthHandler.

I have tried this solution: [module 'tweepy' has no attribute 'OAuthHandler'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41917038/module-tweepy-has-no-attribute-oauthhandler), as well as dozens others. Nothing is working. Even importing everything is not working. This is my code:

import tweepy;

from tweepy import OAuthHandler;

This is my error:

ImportError: cannot import name 'OAuthHandler'

Comment: I answered a similar question here: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/54331325/9216582](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54331325/9216582)

Answer (score 0):

```
import tweepy
from tweepy.auth import OAuthHandler
```

use the above code and see it will works

Comment: I tried this. Got another error:

ImportError: No module named 'tweepy.auth'

Comment: go to terminal in your system and check this command ( pip list ) to verify whether it is installed or not using $pip list

Comment: entering (pip list), $pip list, pip list all come out with the same error:
pip is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file. I don't know where or if I would have installed whatever pip is. Does it download with python?
I suspect tweepy is installed properly because the "import tweepy" line is not showing any error or warning. Wouldn't it be causing problems if it wasn't installed properly?